# Azure blob storage; Derived Column

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to created a derived column from the another column in data that I have in the Azure blob storage; Any pointers on where I should start. The dataset that I am dealing with is a structured one.

```
input dataset= [col_a, col_b, col_c]
output_dataset= [col_a, col_a^2, col_a*3, col_b]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the dataset is not great, you could try following steps.

1. Read all the data from Azure blob storage.
2. Deserialize the data to a dataset.
3. Add a new column to the dataset and calculate the value of this column.
4. Deserialize the dataset and save the data back to Azure blob storage.

Otherwise, you need to read the dataset from Azure blob storage, calculate value of new column and save it to a new place row by row, It depends on how did you store the dataset in blob.

Comment: Thanks Amor for the response on this..I am looking for something similar to the virtual column in the oracle database, where you populate the record in the database and the virtual column gets populated on its own. i want to avoid using spark to fetch the data and schedule this activity with some frequency.

Comment: I haven't found any way to implement this kind of column at storage level. Since Azure Storage Service charges at lower price. I suggest you add a physical column to store the data you wanted to avoid fetching the data with some frequency.